# installing Sublime Text 3 SublimeREPL on python;mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublimetext3, sublimerepl

I install the sublimerepl package on my text editor, everything seems to work fine.

Going to tools -> build system -> sublimerepl_build_system_hack

throws this error in the console

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/MacOS/sublime_plugin.py", line 1034, in run_
    return self.run(**args)
  File "/Users/markchaykovskiy/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/SublimeREPL/sublimerepl_build_system_hack.py", line 16, in run
    RESULTS.put(cmd)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'put'
```

On this test code:

```
name = input('What is your name? ')
print('Hello ', name)
```

Secondly, going to [tools - sublimerepl - python - python-execnet] is the only option i have under python, I see on other videos it gives an option for current file.